# Why isn't the vertex moving the face of the object?

Tags: faces

Hi I'm just learning how to use Blender and got stuck trying to add vertex points to an object that aren't changing the shape of the object.

I know if I press F I can add a new face from the selected vertices.
But is there a more efficient way of doing this? When I add a new face I now have to delete the one under it.  Is there a way to add vertices that are already connected to the face of the object.  (sorry if I'm not using some of these terms correct)

Here's a screenshot of the vertex I added by subdividing two edges, connecting those two vertices, and subdividing that new edge.[image]

Comment: Hello :). This question keeps popping up as unanswered. Please mark one of the answers as accepted **✓**, or post your own solution. Just to keep the site nice and tidy. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.
Just use <kbd>J</kbd> instead to connect the vertices.

**1. Connecting vertices across a face**
*Vertex > Connect vertex path*
Shortcut: <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

**2. Connecting free floating vertices**
*Vertex > New edge/Face from vertices*
Shortcut: <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]